# Dynamically compiling and Running a Hadoop job from another Java File

Tags: java, dynamic, hadoop, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to write a Java file that receives the source code of a MapReduce job, compiles it dynamically and runs the job on a Hadoop cluster. To reach this, I have written 3 methods called compile(), makeJAR() and run_Hadoop_Job(). Everything works fine with the compilation and creation of the JAR file. However, when the job is submitted to Hadoop, as soon as the job starts, it faces problem with finding required Mapper/Reducer classes and throws a ClassNotFoundException for both the Mapper_Class and Reducer_Class ***(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: reza.rCloud.Mapper_Reducer_Classes$Mapper_Class.class)*** . I know that there should be something wrong with how I have referenced the required Mapper/Reducer classes but I was not able to figure it out after several. Any help/suggestion on how to solve the issue is highly appreciated.

**Regarding the details of the project:** I have a file called "rCloud_test/src/reza/Mapper_Reducer_Classes.java" that contains the source code for Mapper_Class and Reducer_Class. This file is ultimately received during the runtime but for now I copied the Hadoop WordCount example in it and store it locally in the same folder as my main class file: rCloud_test/src/reza/Platform2.java.

Here below you can see the main() method of the Platform2.java which is my main class for this project:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Code Execution Started");
    String className = "Mapper_Reducer_Classes";
    Platform2 myPlatform = new Platform2();

    //step 1: compile the received class file dynamically:
    boolean compResult = myPlatform.compile(className); 
    System.out.println(className + ".java compilation result: "+compResult);

    //step 2: make a JAR file out of the compiled file:
    if (compResult) {
        compResult  = myPlatform.makeJAR("jar_file", myPlatform.compilation_Output_Folder);
        System.out.println("JAR creation result: "+compResult);
    } 
    //step 3: Now let's run the Hadoop job:
    if (compResult) {       
        compResult = myPlatform.run_Hadoop_Job(className);
        System.out.println("Running on Hadoop result: "+compResult);
    }
```

The method that is causing me all the problems is the run_Hadoop_Job() which is as below:

```
private boolean run_Hadoop_Job(String className){
try{
    System.out.println("*Starting to run the code on Hadoop...");
    String[] argsTemp = { "project_test/input", "project_test/output" };

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:54310");
    conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "localhost:54311");

    conf.set("mapred.jar", jar_Output_Folder + "/jar_file"+".jar");

    conf.set("libjars", required_Execution_Classes);

    //THIS IS WHERE IT CAN'T FIND THE MENTIONED CLASSES, ALTHOUGH THEY EXIST BOTH ON DISK 
    // AND IN THE CREATED JAR FILE:??????
    System.out.println("Getting Mapper/Reducer package name: " + 
                        Mapper_Reducer_Classes.class.getName());
    conf.set("mapreduce.map.class", "reza.rCloud.Mapper_Reducer_Classes$Mapper_Class");
    conf.set("mapreduce.reduce.class", "reza.rCloud.Mapper_Reducer_Classes$Reducer_Class");

    Job job = new Job(conf, "Hadoop Example for dynamically and programmatically compiling-running a job");
    job.setJarByClass(Platform2.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(argsTemp[0]));
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    Path out = new Path(argsTemp[1]);
    fs.delete(out, true);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(argsTemp[1]));

    //job.submit();
    System.out.println("*and now submitting the job to Hadoop...");
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1); 
    System.out.println("Job Finished!");        
} catch (Exception e) {         
            System.out.println("****************Exception!" ); 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false; 
    }
return true;
}
```

if needed, here's the source code for the compile() method:

```
private boolean compile(String className) {
    String fileToCompile =  JOB_FOLDER   + "/" +className+".java";
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();       
    FileOutputStream errorStream = null;        
    try{
        errorStream = new FileOutputStream(JOB_FOLDER + "/logs/Errors.txt");
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){ 
        //if problem creating the file, default wil be console 
    }   

    int compilationResult = 
            compiler.run(   null, null, errorStream, 
                            "-classpath", required_Compilation_Classes,
                            "-d", compilation_Output_Folder,
                            fileToCompile);
    if (compilationResult == 0) {
        //Compilation is successful:
        return true;
    } else {
        //Compilation Failed:
        return false;
    }   
}
```

and the source code for makeJAR() method:

```
private boolean makeJAR(String outputFileName, String inputDirectory) {
    Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
    manifest.getMainAttributes().put(Attributes.Name.MANIFEST_VERSION,
            "1.0");

    JarOutputStream target = null;                      
    try {       
        target = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                jar_Output_Folder+ "/"  
                + outputFileName+".jar"                      ), manifest);
        add(new File(inputDirectory), target);
    } catch (Exception e) { return false; }
    finally {
        if (target != null)
            try{
                target.close();
            } catch (Exception e) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}

    private void add(File source, JarOutputStream target) throws IOException
{
  BufferedInputStream in = null;
  try
  {
    if (source.isDirectory())
    {
      String name = source.getPath().replace("\\", "/");
      if (!name.isEmpty())
      {
        if (!name.endsWith("/"))
          name += "/";
        JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(name);
        entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
        target.putNextEntry(entry);
        target.closeEntry();
      }
      for (File nestedFile: source.listFiles())
        add(nestedFile, target);
      return;
    }

    JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(source.getPath().replace("\\", "/"));
    entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
    target.putNextEntry(entry);
    in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (true)
    {
      int count = in.read(buffer);
      if (count == -1)
        break;
      target.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    target.closeEntry();
  }
  finally
  {
    if (in != null)
      in.close();
  }
}
```

and finally the fixed parameters used for accessing the files:

```
private String JOB_FOLDER = "/Users/reza/My_Software/rCloud_test/src/reza/rCloud";
private String HADOOP_SOURCE_FOLDER = "/Users/reza/My_Software/hadoop-0.20.2";
private String required_Compilation_Classes = HADOOP_SOURCE_FOLDER + "/hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar";
private String required_Execution_Classes = required_Compilation_Classes + "," +
     "/Users/reza/My_Software/ActorFoundry_dist_ver/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar," +
     "/Users/reza/My_Software/ActorFoundry_dist_ver/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar";
public String compilation_Output_Folder = "/Users/reza/My_Software/rCloud_test/dyn_classes";
private String jar_Output_Folder = "/Users/reza/My_Software/rCloud_test/dyn_jar";
```

As a result of running the Platform2, the structure of the project on disk looks as below:

rCloud_test/classes/reza/rCloud/Platform2.class: contain the Platform2 class
rCloud_test/dyn_classes/reza/rCloud/ contains the classes for Mapper_Reducer_Classes.class, Mapper_Reducer_Classes$Mapper_Class.class, and Mapper_Reducer_Classes$Reducer_Class.class
rCloud_test/dyn_jar/jar_file.jar contains the created jar file

REVSED: here's the source code for the rCloud_test/src/reza/rCloud/Mapper_Reducer_Classes.java:

```
package reza.rCloud;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.InterruptedException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class Mapper_Reducer_Classes {
/**
 * The map class of WordCount.
 */
public static class Mapper_Class
    extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(itr.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
}
/**
 * The reducer class of WordCount
 */
public static class Reducer_Class
    extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable value : values) {
            sum += value.get();
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the package of your compiled mapper and reducer classes? You've got it set as **reza.rCloud** when you're configuring it for hadoop, but does this reflect the package declarations in those classes (and thus the directory structure inside the jar)?

Comment: @Jeffery Theobald: I revised my initial post and added the Mapper_Reducer_Classes.java file as well. As you can see, I added the package reza.rCloud on top of that file too. I also unzipped the /Users/reza/My_Software/rCloud_test/dyn_jar/jar_file.jar and that resulted in the following folders to be created: /Users/reza/My_Software/rCloud_test/dyn_jar/Users/reza/My_Software/rCloud_test/dyn_Classes/reza/rCloud/ which contains Mapper_Reducer_Classes.class, Mapper_Reducer_Classes$Mapper_Class.class, and Mapper_Reducer_Classes$Reducer_Class.class  .So I guess the structure of the JAR fileis also OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set them by using the [setClass()](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html#setClass%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class%29) method :

```
conf.setClass("mapreduce.map.class", 
              Class.forName("reza.rCloud.Mapper_Reducer_Classes$Mapper_Class"),
              Mapper.class);

conf.setClass("mapreduce.reduce.class",
              Class.forName("reza.rCloud.Mapper_Reducer_Classes$Reducer_Class"),
              Reducer.class);
```

Comment: I tried "System.out.println("Class.ForName:"+Class.forName("reza.rCloud.Mapper_Reducer_Classes$Mapper_Class"));" but it still can't find the reza.rCloud.Mapper_Reducer_Classes$Mapper_Class and throws "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: reza.rCloud.Mapper_Reducer_Classes$Mapper_Class"

Comment: Could you post the result of `jar tf jar_file.jar | grep Mapper_Reducer_Classes ` ?

Comment: here's the result:  /Users/reza/My_Software/rCloud_test/dyn_classes/reza/rCloud/Mapper_Reducer_Classes$Mapper_Class.class
/Users/reza/My_Software/rCloud_test/dyn_classes/reza/rCloud/Mapper_Reducer_Classes$Reducer_Class.class
/Users/reza/My_Software/rCloud_test/dyn_classes/reza/rCloud/Mapper_Reducer_Classes.class

Comment: All the required classes are available in the JAR file but for some reason, configuration cannot access them? I think I am missing something here. I should add that a few days ago it suddenly worked fine but when I removed everything and tried to rebuild it, it starts throwing error again. My guess is that I copied some of the classes to some path manually and that made it work for a short period of time. but am not sure what exactly I did?

Comment: `makeJAR()` is creating a directory structure that doesn't correspond to the package declaration of `reza.rCloud` . Mapper_Reducer_Class‌​es.class should be under `/reza/rCloud/`
in your jar file.

Comment: thanks. I tried creating the JAR file manually and it resulted in /reza/rCloud/ as you said. Any idea on how I should fix this?

Comment: also, I tried the code with the manually created JAR and it worked fine. so, your guess is correct and the problem is with the directory structure in the JAR file. now the question is how to fix it?

Comment: First I'd suggest you to create a new question since this isn't Hadoop-related anymore. Also search on SO since there have been surely asked similar questions.

Comment: thanks Lorand. I figured it out. The problem was with using the file's path at the time of adding JAREntries. Anyway, I fixed it. thanks for figuring out the problem. I wasted several days on this.